# How to show default values of multiple values of Product Page?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a Product Page where the values of Short Description, Price, Discount, and Images get changed based upon two variables i.e. Color and Size.

Upon selection of Color, the user needs to select a size.

I want to set default values of all these on page load. I could get the value by selecting Color and then Size but unable to set default value.

My Script:

```
<script src="js/script.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/zoom-image.js"></script>
<script src="js/zoom-main.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $("#colorId").prop("selectedIndex", 1); // here 0 means select first option
        $("#colorId").change();
        $(colorId).trigger('change');
        $("#sizeId").prop("selectedIndex", 1);
    });
    
    function getSizesByColor() {
        var colorId = $("#colorId").val();
        $.post("ajax.php",{getSizesByColor:'getSizesByColor',colorId:colorId},
        function (response) {
            var data = response.split('^');
            $("#sizeId").html(data[1]);
            
        });     
    }
    
</script>
<script>
    function getPriceBySize() {
        var sizeId = $("#sizeId").val();
        $.post("ajax.php",{getPriceBySize:'getPriceBySize',sizeId:sizeId},
        function (response) {
            var data = response.split('^');
            $("#priceId").html(data[1]);
        });     
    }
</script>

<script>
    function getDiscountBySize() {
        var sizeId = $("#sizeId").val();
        $.post("ajax.php",{getDiscountBySize:'getDiscountBySize',sizeId:sizeId},
        function (response) {
            var data = response.split('^');
            $("#discountId").html(data[1]);
        });     
    }
</script>

<script>
    function getDesBySize() {
        var sizeId = $("#sizeId").val();
        $.post("ajax.php",{getDesBySize:'getDesBySize',sizeId:sizeId},
        function (response) {
            var data = response.split('^');
            $("#pvdscId").html(data[1]);
        });     
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Why not just add the [selected attribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/option#selected) to the `<option>` elements that correspond to the default values?